# How to combine multiple text value into a single sql database row

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

may I ask how will I be able to add two text values into a single row in my database?

I've tried the following, but no avail.

```
update tblLeave set AdminRemark='a' + 'b',Status=1,AdminRemarkDate=2019 where id=12
update tblLeave set AdminRemark=('a' + 'b'),Status=1,AdminRemarkDate=2019 where id=12
```

This works `update tblLeaves set AdminRemark=concat('a', 'b'),Status=1,AdminRemarkDate=2019 where id=12`
but when i tried to implement it in my code, it does not.

This is the actual code.

```
$sql="update tblLeave set AdminRemark=concat(:description,:admremarkdate),Status=:status,AdminRemarkDate=:admremarkdate, where id=:admid";
```

This is where i get the problem =

```
AdminRemark=concat(:description,:adminfullname)
```

The result should add two text values into AdminRemark `(AdminRemark = done : John Smith)`

EDIT: I've resolved it guys, I forgot to add `$query->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: did you use `CONCAT()`?

Comment: It worked when I tried using it directly into my database, but with this, It's not pushing through update tblleaves set AdminRemark=concat(:description,:admremarkdate)

Comment: this works - `update tblLeave set AdminRemark=concat('a','b'),Status=1,AdminRemarkDate=2019 where id=12` but when i tested in my code, its not pushing through `$sql="update tblLeave set AdminRemark=concat(:description, :adminfullname),Status=:status,AdminRemarkDate=:admremarkdate where id=:admid";`

Comment: I've resolved it, i forgot to add the line `$query->bindParam(':description',$description,PDO::PARAM_STR);`